# How to get content of HTML body with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get all quotes out of HTML body content.
Currently I'm in this state:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">
<pre> This is my text "with some quotes" and some "more" quotes. </p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Get quotes</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var text = document.body.innerHTML;
var quotes =text.match(/"([^"]+)"/g);
for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
document.write(quotes[i] + "<br />" + "<br />");
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but I get all the quotes that are in my code like this:
    "demo"

```
"with some quotes"

"more"

"button"

"myFunction()"

"([^"

"/g); for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) { document.write(quotes[i] + "

" + "
```

When I really need only this:

```
"with some quotes"

"more"
```

Do you have any ideas how i could fix this? 
I tryed to write the content directly to var text and everything worked, however I would like to get the content out of body automatically.
Your advices will be appreciated.

Comment: Wheres the ending `</pre>`?

Comment: Is it necessary that you use vanilla JS?

Comment: Than maybe `innerText()` would do the trick unless you want the `"` even in the attributs of you html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change

`var text = document.body.innerHTML;`

to

`var text = document.body.innerText;`

To retrieve from the content without including the HTML

Edit: You may want to use a combination of innerText and textContent properties to get a more cross-browser friendly solution if you can't use jQuery.
Examples: http://help.dottoro.com/ljhvexii.php

---

**Update:** This answer was submitted in 2014. `innerText` is supported now by virtually all browsers:

- IE 6+
- Edge all versions
- Firefox 45+
- Chrome 4+
- Safari 3.2+
- Opera 10+

More browser info at [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=innertext)

Comment: Is this even valid in anything but IE?

Comment: I've added additional information based on your comment

Answer (score 2):

Don't access the `body` element, access just the `p` element. You then won't get quoted items from the rest of the document:

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
```